# Chartboost Unity plugin Video rewards always pop up 'reward 1 coins' message ,how can I change it?

Tags: unity-game-engine, ads, chartboost

This message seems no where to modify both in the plugin files or website console. Actually,this should be configurable,because each game won't have the same reward.I wanner just change it to 20 coins reward or not let it appear.
The real rewards will deal with in the complete callback so I don't need such message.
Anyone knows can help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here you have an input:

Move to your Chartboost dashboard and select your app. Once selecte, on the left panel (if using the new dashboard) click on Settings -> Rewarded Video.

There you have two inputfields: Currency name and reward per view.

You can also add custom content to ads. Here you can read more about it:
https://answers.chartboost.com/hc/en-us/articles/201220195-Creatives

Hope it helps!

Comment: It seems like they have changed the website and I can't find the currency name and reward anymore. Any ideas?